# Where can I buy the English translated of Monogatari light novels?

Tags: monogatari-series

After finishing the *Hanamonogatari* anime, I'm interested reading the light novel. I heard that there is the English translation of the *Monogatari* series light novel, so where can I buy them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For North America, I believe *Monogatari* series novels are released by [Vertical](http://www.vertical-inc.com/new/tag/monogatari-series/). For example, [*Kizumonogatari*](http://www.vertical-inc.com/new/tis-the-season-for-vertical/) was released in December 2015.

[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=NISIOISIN&search-alias=books&field-author=NISIOISIN&sort=relevancerank) appears to also have *Monogatari* series novels.

As for the rest, I'm not sure for legitimate sources.